# How to pass parameters correctly to a paypal button (laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, paypal, laravel-blade, shopping-cart

I'm creating a little cart that passes the values of the items you bought to the paypal cart so you can checkout quickly. my problem is that it currently creates a paypal button per item added to the cart. Let me show you.

[image]

Since there are 3 items in the cart, there are 3 buttons. once you look at the source code, its pretty obvious: the code is inside a @foreach column. My question is, how do I initialize the value $id => $details so I can pass around the actual values of the products being processed, so the user doesn't need to manually input the products he or she desires? I havent found a way to do this without using the "@foreach" thingy. Let me show you my code:

this is layout.blade.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>@yield('Carrito')</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/style2.css') }}">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-12 main-section">
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i> Carrito <span class="badge badge-pill badge-danger">{{ count((array) session('cart')) }}</span>
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    <div class="row total-header-section">
                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-6">
                            <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span class="badge badge-pill badge-danger">{{ count((array) session('cart')) }}</span>
                        </div>
                        <?php $total = 0 ?>
                        @foreach((array) session('cart') as $id => $details)
                            <?php $total += $details['price'] * $details['quantity'] ?>
                        @endforeach
                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-6 total-section text-right">
                            <p>Total: <span class="text-info">$ {{ $total }}</span></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    @if(session('cart'))
                        @foreach(session('cart') as $id => $details)
                            <div class="row cart-detail">
                                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-4 cart-detail-img">
                                    <img src="{{ $details['photo'] }}" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-8 col-8 cart-detail-product">
                                    <p>{{ $details['name'] }}</p>
                                    <span class="price text-info"> ${{ $details['price'] }}</span> <span class="count"> Quantity:{{ $details['quantity'] }}</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        @endforeach
                    @endif
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-12 text-center checkout">
                            <a href="{{ url('cart') }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Ver todo</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container page">
    @yield('content')
</div>
@yield('scripts')
</body>
</html>
```

and this is cart.blade.php

```
@extends('layout')
@section('title', 'Cart')
@section('content')
    <table id="cart" class="table table-hover table-condensed">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width:50%">Producto</th>
            <th style="width:10%">Precio</th>
            <th style="width:8%">Cantidad</th>
            <th style="width:22%" class="text-center">Subtotal</th>
            <th style="width:10%"></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php $total = 0 ?>
        @if(session('cart'))
            @foreach(session('cart') as $id => $details)
                <?php $total += $details['price'] * $details['quantity'] ?>
                <tr>
                    <td data-th="Product">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-3 hidden-xs"><img src="{{ $details['photo'] }}" width="100" height="100" class="img-responsive"/></div>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <h4 class="nomargin">{{ $details['name'] }}</h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-th="Price">${{ $details['price'] }}</td>
                    <td data-th="Quantity">
                        <input type="number" value="{{ $details['quantity'] }}" class="form-control quantity" />
                    </td>
                    <td data-th="Subtotal" class="text-center">${{ $details['price'] * $details['quantity'] }}</td>
                    <td class="actions" data-th="">
                        <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm update-cart" data-id="{{ $id }}"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></button>
                        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove-from-cart" data-id="{{ $id }}"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            @endforeach
        @endif
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
        <tr class="visible-xs">
            <td class="text-center"><strong>Total {{ $total }}</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="{{ url('/products') }}" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i> Seguir comprando</a></td>
            <td colspan="2" class="hidden-xs"></td>
            <td class="hidden-xs text-center"><strong>Total ${{ $total }}</strong></td>

        <!-- the paypal button part -->


            @if(session('cart'))
            @foreach(session('cart') as $id => $details)
            <form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" >
                <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
                <input type="hidden" name="business" value="notanothergenericaddress@gmail.com">
                <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
                <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="{{ $details['name'] }}">
                <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="{{ $details['price'] }}">
                <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="MXN">
                <input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="products">
                <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
                <input type="hidden" name="tax_rate" value="15.000">
                <input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="500.00">
                <input type="hidden" name="add" value="{{ $details['quantity'] }}">
                <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-ShopCartBF:btn_cart_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest">
                <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/es_XC/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal, la forma más segura y rápida de pagar en línea.">
                    <img alt=""  src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/es_XC/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
                </form>
                @endforeach
                @endif
        </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of add to cart buttons, render a single button using [cart upload](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/cart-upload/). However, this is all very old. Instead of these HTML buttons, you should integrate the current version of [PayPal Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/set-up-standard-payments/).

---

Since you have a server, make two routes:, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls). These routes should return only JSON data (no HTML or text). The latter one should (on success) store the payment details in your database before it does the return (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, the PayPal transaction ID)

Pair those two routes with the following approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server